# Assertion failed src.type in Utils.matToBitmap

Tags: android, opencv

i want to calculate `OpticalFlow` and then show that but i get error.
my code:

```
Bitmap resultBitmap = mResultBitmaps.poll();
Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Mat flow = new Mat(image.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
Video.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(image, Prev_image, flow,0.5,1, 1, 1, 7,1.5,1);
Utils.matToBitmap(flow, resultBitmap, true);
```

but i get this error :

`Assertion failed (src.type() == CV_8UC1 || src.type() == CV_8UC3 || src.type() == CV_8UC4) in void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean)`

and when I debug flow is :

`Mat [ 320*320*CV_32FC2, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x77dd5148, dataAddr=0x77c7e010 ]`

what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flow is a 2 channel 32 bit floating point number. As the error says, the input needs to be CV_8U either 1, 3 or 4 channels. You will need to decide how you want to represent the 2 channel data. For example, split the channels and use convertTo to convert each to CV_8U to give you two images.